# Java class inheritance/interface implementation principle

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, inheritance, interface

I am not sure of using inheritance / interface implementation in particular situation.

In my simple Spring MVC application I have @Entity class TennisPlayer, which is inherited from abstract class Player (TennisPlayer adds some attributes).

Also I have class TennisPlayerForm, which is inherited from abstract class PlayerForm (TennisPlayerForm adds some attributes again).

User fills the form about tennis player in .jsp page and TennisPlayerForm object is used to represent filled values and then on the basis of this object is created TennisPlayer object and saved into database.

Creation of TennisPlayer object is responsibility of class TennisPlayerDbService. This class is implementation of interface PlayerService.

I have following @Controller, which handles requests:

```
@Controller
public class NewPlayerController {

    @Resource(name="tennisPlayerService")
    private PlayerService playerService;


    //omitted RequestMethod.GET handler method


    @RequestMapping(value = "/newplayer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newplayer(Locale locale, @ModelAttribute("tennisPlayerForm") @Valid TennisPlayerForm tennisPlayerForm,
        BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        playerService.createPlayer(tennisPlayerForm);

        return "redirect:/allplayers";
    }
}
```

Part of my source code looks like this:

```
public interface PlayerService {

    public void createPlayer(PlayerForm playerForm);
}

@Service(value="tennisPlayerService")
public class TennisPlayerDbService implements PlayerService {

    private TennisPlayerDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(TennisPlayerDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public void createPlayer(PlayerForm playerForm) {
        TennisPlayerForm tennisPlayerForm = null;

        if (playerForm instanceof TennisPlayerForm) {
            tennisPlayerForm = (TennisPlayerForm) playerForm;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be of type TennisPlayerForm.");
        }


        TennisPlayer player = new TennisPlayer();

        player.setName(tennisPlayerForm.getName());
        player.setSurname(tennisPlayerForm.getSurname());
        player.setAge(tennisPlayerForm.getAge());
        player.setRacket(tennisPlayerForm.getRacket());
        player.setRanking(tennisPlayerForm.getRanking());
        player.setSponsor(tennisPlayerForm.getSponsor());
        player.setCoach(tennisPlayerForm.getCoach());
        player.setClub(tennisPlayerForm.getClub());

        dao.saveAndFlush(player);
    }
}
```

Is it justified to use inheritance and interface implementations like this in this situation, when concrete implementation of PlayerService (TennisPlayerDbService) expects instance of particular class, although these potential classes have common parent?

Comment: You could use the TennisPlayer class instead of the form class in your form, if you're careful. Also, see dozer for easily copying values between objects.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I thought about this solution, but is it a good practise to combine javax.validation annotations with javax.persistence annotations in one class? After all, *PlayerForm is DTO type of object whereas *Player is representation of an entity...

Comment: If you're saving an object's data, and want to ensure it's validity, then yes. I only use Form Backing Objects when a form's data is significantly different than a particular entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem according to your comments and answers.

I deleted PlayerForm abstract class, TennisPlayerForm and mixed javax.validation and javax.persistence annotations in @Entity classes Player and Tennis Player.

Previously mentioned code now looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class NewPlayerController {

    @Resource(name="tennisPlayerService")
    private PlayerService<TennisPlayer> playerService;

    //omitted RequestMethod.GET handler method  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newplayer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newplayer(Locale locale, @ModelAttribute("tennisPlayer") @Valid TennisPlayer tennisPlayer,
        BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "newplayer";
        }

        playerService.createPlayer(tennisPlayer);

        MessageUtil.flash(locale, redirectAttributes, "success", "signup.success");

        return "redirect:/allplayers";

    }
}

public interface PlayerService<T extends Player> {

    public void createPlayer(T player);

    public List<T> getAllPlayers();
}

@Service(value="tennisPlayerService")
public class TennisPlayerDbService implements PlayerService<TennisPlayer> {

    private TennisPlayerDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    public void setDao(TennisPlayerDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    public void createPlayer(TennisPlayer player) {     
        dao.saveAndFlush(player);
    }

    @Override
    public List<TennisPlayer> getAllPlayers() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally your service does not need to know you are working with a form. Your form is purely created to be the model in the model-view-controller architecture of your webpage. (your jsp being the view and your controller being the c-part)

Are you also planning on using other types of players than a `TennisPlayer`? If not it all seems like premature optimisation and you should keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer. From this simplicity point of view you are right - it is premature optimisation, but it's entrance examination in new company, where I want to work, so I have to ensure some extensibility by creating new types of Players, for example GolfPlayer etc. :) EDIT: The *Form naming convention is not important here, important is that these types of classes hold information, which should be saved into DB.

Comment: XxxPlayerForm is just a data transfer object (DTO) only used to hold entered data. It's not an object subject to OO principles.

Comment: So you think that from extensibility point of view it's ok? My point is the fact, that PlayerService declares that it accepts any subclass of PlayerForm, but during runtime that's not true -> it throws IllegalArgumentException when you put there object of "wrong" subclass of PlayerForm...

Comment: That's a possible flaw in the design. I'd do it with interfaces and using generics to avoid that runtime checking.